# Multilang Webites : Where to store the langs list?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization

We have a website translated in almost thirty languages. Each article will have a field saying which language it've been written for.

I wonder what's the best rails way to implement this. Create a full model Language with something like this :

```
Class Language
    has_many :article
end
Class Article
    belongs_to :language
end
```

Or hardcode this directly in a field of the articles table with a constant to list all the available langs. (Mainly to show it in a drop-down list) :

```
LANG_LIST = {:en => 'english', :de => 'german', :fr => 'french' ...}
```

The two work, but what's the best rails way and the cleanest to maintain ?

Thanks for your opinion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a language attribute on the article model to store the information, your second option may be just enough.

A language model would just be too much for no real gain, i think.

If you want to encapsulate it further, you can create a module that extends your model to instance methods that handle languages. And that is probably the preferred way, if you want to make things clean.

Should you wish to stick with a model, remember that you can use the delegate helper to make things transparent to your language model. So, instead of article.language.locale, you can directly call article.language_locale (a very subtle but important design pattern).

Many things that you can do, but i will probably keep it simple with a module here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of i18n feature but it seems more views and helper oriented than a way to deal with languages inside the models.

Comment: Ok, I hardly see what you mean by a module that extends your model to instance methods that handle languages?

Comment: In Rails, you can create a module that is not an actual model, but some defined methods. Say that you call it language_setter.rb and you put it in /lib (standard place). You can create all your logic for the languages there, and then include the module in your article model, that can use its methods as class or instance methods(depends on whether you include or extend). http://www.postal-code.com/mrhappy/blog/2007/02/06/rails-extending-classes-creating-mixins/